# General Office 365

Tags: office-365

I've got a Office 365 Business Essentials subscription with GoDaddy, but I'll be switching to the Microsoft-hosted version when my subscription ends.
As I'm a student I'm quite interested in the University subscription, as it seems to be a great value.

I just want to make sure that the University subscription also allows the use of custom domain names. At least one, preferably more. The Microsoft site states that most 365 packages include the same domain management features, but I can't seem to find a full feature comparison.

TL;DR - Can I use Office 365 with custom domains, or should I get another subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom domains in Office 365 comes in every subscription plan available, and is a part of the Office 365 platform. The upper limit is 900, and I think that cover every organizational need you may have:

> You can add up to 900 domains to your Office 365 subscription.

The downside is that you can’t use second-level or third-level domains such as registration.university.edu. To implement that you’ll need a business or enterprise subscription plan.

Reference: [Office 365 Plan Options](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office-365-plan-options.aspx) and [Domains](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office-365-domains.aspx)